Not able to open or call the current open file with xlwings
I'm not able to open or call the current active workbook using xlwings.
I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.5 and xlwings  v0.31.10.
I keep getting this error (I'm running the .py file out of 4. Master):
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'mount_point' where it is not associated with a value

My Excel file is on a SharePoint which is synced to my OneDrive folder locally.
I've also configured ONEDRIVE_CONSUMER_MAC (to /Users/John/OneDrive - MyCompany) and ONEDRIVE_COMMERCIAL_MAC (to /Users/John/OneDrive - MyCompany 2) in my environment variables in  ~/.bash_profile
I've tried something very simple but can't get it to work.
import xlwings as xw

def getWB():
    try:
        wb =xw.Book.caller() #never works
    except:
        wb = xw.Book("/Users/John/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-MyCompany/Project XYZ/2. Excel/4. Master/Name of Excel file.xlsm").set_mock_caller()
        wb =xw.Book.caller()
    return wb

def main():
    wb = getWB()
    sheet = wb.sheets[0]
    if sheet["E4"].value == "Hello xlwings!":
        sheet["E4"].value = "Bye xlwings!"
    else:
        sheet["E4"].value = "Hello xlwings!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = xw.App()
    main()

I'd appreciate any help!
Thank you!

You can't have python use xw.Book.caller() directly, so yes it will always fail. But you seem to understand that since the error code then uses set_mock_caller()

Are you trying to connect to an already running instance of Excel?
If a workbook called 'foo.xlsx' is already open and you want to access it then...
import xlwings as xw

"""
def getWB():
    try:
        wb =xw.Book.caller() #never works
    except:
        wb = xw.Book("/Users/John/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-MyCompany/Project XYZ/2. Excel/4. Master/Name of Excel file.xlsm").set_mock_caller()
        wb =xw.Book.caller()
    return wb
"""

def main():
    ### Connect to the already open Excel workbook called 'foo.xlsx' or open if its not. 
    wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')  

    sheet = wb.sheets[0]
    if sheet["E4"].value == "Hello xlwings!":
        sheet["E4"].value = "Bye xlwings!"
    else:
        sheet["E4"].value = "Hello xlwings!"

    ### Waiting to end
    input("Waiting!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = xw.App(visible=False)
    main()

It is usually better to use in a context manager for clean up
though this will close the workbook as well at the end if it wasn't already open.
import xlwings as xw


with xw.App(visible=False) as xl:
    ### Connect to the already open Excel workbook called 'foo.xlsx' or open if its not. 
    wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')

    sheet = wb.sheets[0]
    if sheet["E4"].value == "Hello xlwings!":
        sheet["E4"].value = "Bye xlwings!"
    else:
        sheet["E4"].value = "Hello xlwings!"

    input("Waiting!")

Disclaimer
This is true for windows but expect that MACOS would act the same.

Yes, I am trying to access an open Excel instance. I tried your code but I still get "UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'mount_point' where it is not associated with a value". If I close my Excel file and only run your code it works. But I'd like to access an open instance.

Could be a sharepoint issue then given the 'mount point' is not a local drive. Have you or can you copy the Excel file to a local directory to see if the same error occurs running from there? In my limited environment I tested a workbook running on onedrive. MACOS may also impose different circumstances in this environment. I don't have any MACOS to check with,

So I moved the file to a local folder and it actually works in that scenario. I tried to then follow the steps in the OneDrive/SharePoint setup documentation on xlwings.com but I keep getting the same error...

From the xlwings code, there is is only one place the variable mountPoint is set and that is in the Xlwings utils.py file; for url_namespace, mount_point in url_to_mount.items(): around line 619. Does that match with your traceback? Do you have an IDE that you can do some debugging, to see what's happening there?
